# why implement abstractmethod as staticmethod

Tags: python, inheritance, abstract

I'm learning python design patterns from github repo [faif/python-patterns](https://github.com/faif/python-patterns) and found the example [chain_of_responsibility](https://github.com/faif/python-patterns/blob/master/patterns/behavioral/chain_of_responsibility.py#L52) implements *abstractmethod* `check_range` as *staticmethod*.

My question is, is there any benefit other than less typing a `self`?

Simplify code is

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod


class A(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def foo(self, x):
        pass


class B(A):
    @staticmethod
    def foo(x):
        print("B.foo", x)


# both the two works
B.foo(1)

b = B()
b.foo(2)
```

Comment: It depends on *why* `A` requires its subclasses to implement a method named `foo`. What `abc` provides is fairly limited. Despite the name `abstractmethod`, the only thing it requires is that the *name* `foo` be bound to *something* concrete in a subclass. It doesn't even have to be a method: it could be a list, an int, anything, as long as (implementation detail to follow) it doesn't have an `__isabstractmethod__` attribute set to `True`.

Comment: *"My question is, is there any benefit other than less typing a self?"* - this is not a matter of less typing or a benefit. This changes the nature of the method. Being a static method it means it ***doesn't have access to an instance***

Comment: but it can still be called by instance, that looks strange to me.

Comment: Nothing about that example strikes me as particularly idiomatic Python. `Handler` is just a linked list of functions, none of which particularly need to be wrapped in a subclass of `Handler`. Python can already store a list of functions; this is the kind of design you'd seen in Java, where functions are not first-class objects and you have to wrap them as methods of some other object to store them in a list.

Comment: Decorating a method as static allows it to be called from an instance of the class object. But like @Tomerikoo said, static methods have no access to the instance itself nor does it get the class object as a argument. The reason someone would do that could be a few different reasons. One being that whoever would label is static is saying this method should NOT have access to the instance since either it doesn't need to or that its state is handle else where and giving it instance access could make it harder to understand what is going on. These are just the first two that come to my head

Comment: @chepner 'Nothing about that example strikes me...' --- agree this sample seems overdesigned. i'm learning just because this repo has so many stars (>30k by now)

Comment: @TeddyBearSuicide 'static allows it to be called from an instance...' this is just opposite of my knowledge, am i missing something?

Comment: All three types of methods can be called using an instance. An instance method receives the instance itself as its first argument; a class method receives the type of the instance as its first argument; a static method simply doesn't receive any implicit first argument.

Comment: @LeiYang If this was a static method in other languages like C# or Java then you would be correct. Python though handles it differently. chepner explains the three types of methods and how they differ in arguments. They do differ in other ways but for the most part you can ignore the other ways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no particular benefit. Sure, not all the `check_range` methods need an instance of the handler class that defines it, so they are declared as static methods.

But there's no reason any of the classes in your linked page need to exist in the first place, because in Python you can just store a function itself in a list, rather than storing some other dummy object that has an equivalent method.

Here's how you can implement "chain of responsibility" in Python idiomatically.

```
def check_range0(request):
    return request in range(10)

# A closure can be used in place of a class
def make_check_range1():
    start = 10
    stop = 20
    return lambda request: request in range(start, stop)

# Another way of using a closure in place of a class
def make_check_range2(start, stop):
    return lambda request: request in range(start, stop)


def fallback(request):
    print("No handler for {request}")

handlers = [check_range0, make_check_range1(), make_check_range2(20, 30)]


for request in requests:
    if any((handler:=f)(request) for f in handlers):
        print(f"{request} handled by {handler.__name__}")
    else:
        fallback(request)
```

A simple list takes the place of the linked list implied by `Handler`. Each subclass of `Handler` is replaced by a regular function (or a function that returns a closure, just to emphasize that a class is not necessary to provide or store state). The `any` function implements the iteration provided by `Handler.handle`.

If you really want a handler class, you can define it more simply than the example.

```
class Handler(ABC):
    def __init__(self, handlers=None):
        if handlers is None:
            handlers = []
        self.handlers = handlers
        self.fallback = lambda request: pass

    def add_handler(self, f):
        self.handlers.append(f)

    # Barely necessary; you can set the fallback
    # attribute on a Handler instance yourself.
    def set_fallback(self, f):
        self.fallback = f

    def handle(self, request):
        # An alternative to any()
        for h in self.handlers:
            if h(request):
                break
        else:
            self.fallback(request)

h = Handler([check_range0])
h.add_handler(make_check_range1())
h.add_handler(make_check_range2(20, 30))

def fallback(request):
    print(f"No handler for {request}"

h.fallback = fallback
# h.set_fallback(fallback)

for request in requests:
    h.handle(request)
```